# .htaccess rule not working without HTTP redirect [R]

Tags: linux, apache, htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using the following .htaccess with Wordpress to remove index.php from the visible URL. This works but forces an http redirect so the URL changes in the browser window. If I remove the [R] it no longer works. Why would this happen?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [R]
```

Comment: Could you clarify the 'it no longer works' part? Are you getting 404 errors?

Comment: Sorry no it is going to the index.php. It seems like the query string is getting dropped or something. I want urls like domain.com/products/rental-options/ to redirect to domain.com/index.php/products/rental-options/ without changing the URL in the address bar

Comment: Have you had a look at the [RewriteLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog)? I've found it's extremely helpful with a high `RewriteLogLevel`. Note this needs to be set in your server config, not in .htaccess.

Comment: It's a shared hosting account so I'm sticking with .htaccess. My hands are tied with most server config files.

Comment: You could well be using the query string, it is dropped by default in RewriteRules. You can add [QSA] to keep the query string. But you should probably also take a look at this page: http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Creating_and_editing_.28.htaccess.29

Comment: Just use the default htaccess wordpress provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that I forgot a major piece. I was skipping over the fact that the query string needed to be sent to the get variable q.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're mixing `Wordpress` itself, which tries to do a redirect, and the `RewriteRule`, where *you don't have to do a redirect*: it's rewritten internally *before* arriving to Php, thus *before* arriving to `Wordpress`. If you just stop rewriting and add the `QSA` flag to always keep the query string, this should do the trick.

Try to do this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

If it doesn't work, try to do this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

If it doesn't work, try to do this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

And if that's not enough:

### Two hints:

If you're not in a hosted environment (= if it's your own server and you can modify the virtual hosts, not only the `.htaccess` files), try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down such problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

---

My favorite tool to check for regexp:

http://www.quanetic.com/Regex (don't forget to choose ereg(POSIX) instead of preg(PCRE)!)

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work and this is shared hosting so no RewriteLog

Comment: Answer updated, tell me if it worked ;)